# GridLayout two tables among each other

Tags: java, swt, grid-layout

I want to create a dialog with two tables in it. This two tables have to share the  space equal in vertical align. A scrollbar has to appear if to many elements in the table.

```
@Override
protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) {
    createSecondDialog();
    GridLayoutFactory layout = GridLayoutFactory.fillDefaults().numColumns(
            1);
    GridDataFactory grid = GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().grab(true, false);

    Composite composite = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);
    layout.applyTo(composite);

    composite.setBackground(Display.getDefault().getSystemColor(
            SWT.COLOR_CYAN));

    Composite section = new Composite(composite, SWT.NONE);
    layout.applyTo(section);
    grid.applyTo(section);

    createTable(section);
    createTable(section);

    return composite;
}

private TableViewer createTable(Composite area) {
    CheckboxTableViewer table = CheckboxTableViewer.newCheckList(area,
            SWT.READ_ONLY | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.MULTI | SWT.V_SCROLL);

    table.getTable().setBackground(
            Display.getDefault().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_DARK_GRAY));
    GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().grab(true, false).
            .applyTo(table.getTable());

    table.setLabelProvider(new LabelProvider() {
        @Override
        public String getText(Object element) {
            if (element instanceof String) {
                return (String) element;
            }
            return "Test";
        }
    });

    table.setContentProvider(ArrayContentProvider.getInstance());
    Collection<String> input = new ArrayList<String>();
    fillArrayList(input);
    table.setInput(input);
    table.getTable().setHeaderVisible(true);
    table.getTable().setLinesVisible(true);

    Button copyButton = new Button(area, SWT.PUSH);
    GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().align(SWT.END, SWT.FILL)
            .applyTo(copyButton);
    copyButton.setText("Instant Copy");
    copyButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent selectionevent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    return table;
}
```

I am struggeling with it and do not know the answer to achieve my requirment.

Thanks for help!

Comment: The code you have, what does that look like in the end? How does it differ from what you try to achieve?

Comment: The tables will not be restricted in the height. If I have 500 items per table I do not get the scrollbar. The table goes out of the window. My desire is to get a dialog, lets say with 550 pixel heigt and in this window 2 tables with a height of 250 pixel and if the items in the table will be more than the table can show the table has to get a scrollbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restrict the height of the `Dialog` by overriding the method `getInitialSize()`. Then just use the `GridLayout` with one column and set a `GridData` to both tables telling them to expand in both directions. Here is an example:

```
public MyDialog(Shell parentShell)
{
    super(parentShell);
}

@Override
protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent)
{
    Composite container = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);
    container.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

    createTable(container);
    createTable(container);

    return container;
}

private void createTable(Composite parent)
{
    Table table = new Table(parent, SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.BORDER);
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);

    TableColumn column = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
    column.setText("Column");

    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {
        new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE).setText("Item " + i);
    }

    column.pack();

    table.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
}

@Override
protected boolean isResizable()
{
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void configureShell(Shell newShell)
{
    super.configureShell(newShell);
    newShell.setText("StackOverflow");
}

@Override
protected Point getInitialSize()
{
    return new Point(450, 300);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new MyDialog(new Shell()).open();
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]